# Photos.app not combining some CR2(RAW)+JPG flies from Canon 60D

Tags: iphone, photos.app, canon

When importing RAW+JPG pictures from my Canon 60D to Apple Photos on macOS 10.15, some are combined, most are separated. How can I fix all of this? I imported about 300 pictures before this started to happen. I tried using HoudahGeo to shift the times around, hoping that this might make a difference, because I took the pictures in 6 different time zones and forgot to change the camera time at some points.